# How to cluster names

Tags: python, text, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis, levenshtein-distance

I have a dataset of words in a non-semantic context, basically names. I want to perform an act of grouping all the similar ones (say samantha, samanta, sammanta, samaynta.. ) in the same groups.
Since it is a non-semantic context, I cannot vectorize the data using TF-IDF or something else, so I am using the data as it is.

Notice that, I tried using clustering, I used DBSCAN with a custom distance metric (levenshtein), and Polyfuzz. Both gave some decent results, but they were not enough, the former gave a lot of misclusterings, and the later missed a lot of data. I tried searching on the internet for ways to approach this, but weirdly couldn't find any. All were in semantic contexts using TF-IDF and NLP technologies.

note : the dataset is relatively big (around 400.000 or more names)

I have been stuck in this, and would appreciate help, insight, or propositions in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

For clustering you need a *distance metric*, such as the Levenshtein distance. If that does not give you the desired result, you need to use another one.

I would start by defining what you mean by **similar**: obviously it is not similarity in spelling, as otherwise the Levenshtein distance should work. What else is there? From your example it seems like the initail characters are important, so maybe use a string comparison that is weighted towards the beginning of a word.

Another approach you could use is using an algorithm tailored to names, such as [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).

Comment: Actually, the problem does not reside in the distance metric, but rather in the grouping process. Indeed, the distance I used and I will probably use is Levenshtein distance for the similarity between strings, but I am having big troubles with the grouping process. I tried using clustering, but the  existing algorithms use mainly numeric data, which is not my case, so the results are not sufficient. I thought of vetorizing my names, but again, I did not find an efficient way of doing so, most vectorizing methods of NLP use contexts, which I don't have (ex; TF-IDF...) -- So am stuck still

Comment: Clustering works fine with the problem you describe. It doesn't matter what the kind of data is, as long as there is a suitable distance metric.